# AJAX post caching using browser navigation buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post, browser-cache

The difference between browser implementations strikes back!...

I have a report page that gets its data using a jQuery AJAX post. Click away from this page and hit back button in the browser produces these results:

IE/Chrome: The report host page loads from the cache (no server request made). The AJAX post is resent to the server. OK fair enough, plenty of online resources tell me that this is usual behaviour - AJAX posts are never cached. So why...

Firefox: Both the report host page and the AJAX post loads from the cache.

1. Which implementation is correct?
2. Can I force IE and Chrome to behave like FF because, in fact, this is the behaviour I'm looking for. For me, using the navigation buttons, should not resend the request to the server.

Oh, and to throw a potential spanner in the works, I'm browsing in HTTPS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });`

Comment: You should really explain that this is a global change that will prevent **all** ajax calls from caching. It may not be what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Just set `cache:false` in your ajax call

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/